# Being asked to log into a different account to update Xcode?

Tags: applications, mac-appstore, xcode

I wanted to update Xcode 5 to Xcode 6, but the App Store said I had updates available for other accounts. I then uninstalled Xcode but now when I go to the App Store it still says Update rather than Free?

Comment: bit confusing, but it might be me. Obviously you have 2 or more Apple accounts, and under one of them you got the Xcode. Why is it that you cant update it from that account?

Comment: Uninstalling something from the App Store does not change the fact you previously "purchased" it (even if it was free). It will not show the Free button again, instead it should show "reinstall" or something similar (or possibly an iCloud icon). That said, with Xcode you may not have removed everything for the system to know it's gone.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely (well I presume) because you installed the application on another apple ID, the one it is asking you to enter. There is no way around it other then to enter it.